# Scrolling back in the history with pdCurses

Tags: c, scroll, curses

Hello and have a nice day..

So i wrote this simple app with curses that scrolls down or up , when you are pressing the `page-down`  or `page-up` button.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void)
{
    int ch;

    initscr();
    cbreak();
    keypad(stdscr,TRUE);
    idlok(stdscr,TRUE);
    scrollok(stdscr,TRUE);

    printw("Welcome!");
    refresh();


    ch = getch();
    while(ch != 'q'){
        if(ch == KEY_PPAGE){
            scrl(-1);
            refresh();
        }
        else
        {
            scrl(1);
            refresh();
        }
        ch = getch();
    }

    endwin();
    return 0;

}
```

The problem is that if the world "Welcome" goes out of the window , then you cannot bring it back with the opposite button. I thought that something like this will be solved by increasing window buffer. But don't know how such a thing will be done and if its good to be done.

Is there any idea / hint to help me solve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I use curses in python, and the way I solve this issue is to have a list-like data structure attached to the window which holds all lines to be remembered, as well as an index which denotes the first visible line. From there you can figure out what lines should be visible, and recalculate as necessary.

One such implementation in python using Unicurses can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/1622523). It's not in C but I hope it helps.